# ffmpeg hls muxer is missing codec info in master playlist when codecs are copied from input

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

ffmpeg hls muxer has the option to set master playlist but the created playlist is missing the important codec information.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i <input> -c copy -f hls -master_pl_name master.m3u8  stream.m3u8
```

Expected:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=77595,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.64001f,mp4a.40.2"
stream.m3u8
```

Instead I get this

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=77595,RESOLUTION=1280x720
stream.m3u8
```

Is there a way to make ffmpeg set the codec info in playlist from the input source? It works as expected if I encode the input using libx264 but I do not want to do any expensive encoding but copy the codecs from the input.

Answer (score 1):

That is because of `-c copy`; tell `ffmpeg` about video & audio CODECs and stream rates using `-tag:v:0 hvc1 -b:v:0 2000k` and `-tag:a:0 mp4a -b:a:0 128k`.